# Optimization - Finding the most committed to subversion directory month by month

Tags: sql, t-sql, optimization, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have two databases. One is a subversion log with the revision number and the date and the other contains revision numbers and paths altered during the revision. My query finds the directory most committed to on a per-month basis. The problem is that it takes several minutes to run. Can anyone help me optimize this beastly query? I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

```
SELECT   [Directory]
    ,[Month]
    ,COUNT([PathMonth]) OVER (PARTITION BY [PathMonth]) AS [Count] INTO ##temp
FROM
    (SELECT  [Path]
            ,[Month]
            ,[Directory]
            ,[Directory] + [Month] AS [PathMonth]
        FROM
            (SELECT [Path]
                    ,SUBSTRING([Path], 0, LEN([Path]) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([Path])) + 1) AS [Directory]
                    ,CONVERT(CHAR(4), [LogDate], 120) + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(2), [LogDate], 110) AS [Month]
            FROM [SubversionLog] JOIN [PathsLog] ON [SubversionLog].[Revision] = [PathsLog].[Revision]
            WHERE [Path] LIKE '/%/%/%/_%'
            ) one) two
    ORDER BY [Month]
SELECT * INTO ##tempTwo
FROM ##temp
GROUP BY [Directory], [Month], [Count]

SELECT    t1.[Directory]
         ,t1.[Month]
         ,t1.[Count]
    FROM ##tempTwo t1 LEFT JOIN ##tempTwo t2 ON t1.[Month] = t2.[Month] AND t1.[Count] < t2.[Count]
    WHERE t2.[Count] IS NULL
    GROUP BY t1.[Directory], t1.[Month], t1.[Count]
    ORDER BY [Month] DESC


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ##temp)
    DROP TABLE ##temp

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ##tempTwo)
    DROP TABLE ##tempTwo
```

Half of this work is to format the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS timestamp into YYYY-MM and convert the filename paths into directories.

Comment: I'd start by looking at your SubversionLog JOIN PathsLog portion of the query. Is Revision indexed? How many paths don't meet that format because that lookup will be doing some sort of scan. If you've got prior months, filter that out on the most recent month to limit rows read - prior dates shouldn't change, right? Store all of this in a permanent table for reference and you'll be able to compare the existing months to the newly added months without re-analyzing everything again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is your version control, I am guessing you probably don't have more than a couple hundred thousand rows in the table. It wouldn't be the end of the world to run through both tables, but like Peter Schott says, it would be good index Revision:

```
CREATE nonclustered index <name> on SubversionLog (revision)
CREATE nonclustered index <name> on PathsLog (revision)
```

From personal experience, I don't think that doing a few string manipulations is severely slowing you down. I do think creating multiple temporary tables is slowing you down,  since you are creating a new row for most rows in your original tables, and your temp tables are not indexed. Hence, I recommend getting rid of those temporary tables, and simplifying your query:

```
;with filteredData as (
    SELECT [path], 
           Substring([path], 0, Len([path]) - Charindex('/', 
                                              Reverse([path])) + 1) 
                   AS 
           [Directory], 
           CONVERT(CHAR(4), [logdate], 120) + '-' 
           + CONVERT(CHAR(2), [logdate], 110) 
                   AS [Month] 
    FROM   [subversionlog] 
           JOIN [pathslog] 
             ON [subversionlog].[revision] = [pathslog].[revision] 
    WHERE  [path] LIKE '/%/%/%/_%'
), countRevisions as (
    SELECT [month], 
           [directory], 
           count(*) as [Count]
    FROM filteredData
    GROUP BY [MONTH], [directory]
), rankDirectories as (
    SELECT *, RANK() over (partition by month order by count desc) as [Rank]
    from countRevisions
)
select [month], [directory], [count]
from rankDirectories
WHERE [rank] = 1
```

EDIT:

I don't think there's much more you can do without caching some results. You should take a look at the query plan to see what needs to be optimized. I am guessing it's in the grouping, ordering, and/or ranking, possibly joining or key lookup. For the key lookup and joining, you can create covering indices. For the other stuff, you'll need to cache the results. I would not cache with a real table since that would mean an extra table to keep up to date. Instead, I would use a materialized view so that SQL Server keeps it updated for you. Sure this means that updates would be slower, but at a few updates a minute (for a source control log), I don't think this would be a huge problem.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. You made my query about 20x faster.

Comment: @sirdank 20x faster than a few minutes means that the query still takes more than a few seconds, right? I added a few more suggestions that should bring the query down to less than a second.